# Connectivity P/invoke to Delphi 5

Tags: .net, delphi

Because MS only supports their own languages in code equivalent to Delphi *.dcu, 
and because their is no msdn for library P/invoke.   I have no connectivity to P/invoke

Has any one got any idea's for connectivity
As a dll do I use loadlibrary and doing so its defeating the purpose
Is P/invoke just extra code to connect to .com
The only thing it offers is universal error messaging as I see.

Has any one got any idea's for connectivity becuse it looks like its what every one is doing to future proff my projects.

Best Regards,
Lex Dean

Comment: Question lacks clarity.  Are you wanting to call .net managed code from Delphi unmanaged code, or the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an old version of Delphi and their are many users with an old version of delphi that need/desire a .net connection.

I cannot find P/Invoke documention to use P/Invoke that I have no option at the moment but to try and convert Visual C# Code to make connectivity to .net if its possible.